Can NetSuite programmatically clone/copy an item on a sales order in a SuiteLet?
I want to clone/copy an item on a Sales Order. I want to copy the first item on the items sublist from the Sales Order.
I have a UserEventScript that adds a SuiteLet' button to clone/copy the item.
What I am trying to do is

Get the Sales Order
Get the fields in the item sublist from the Sales Order
Then I have an array with excluded fields; I use the array to evict adding those fields to the auxiliary object I will use to copy the other properties
I have several arrays to indicate the field type while I copy the values
I add a new line to the items using salesOrder.selectNewLine({ sublistId: 'item' });
I iterate through the auxiliary object to copy the properties
I try to commit the new line

I get the following error

{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"USER_ERROR","message":"Please choose an item to add","id":"","stack":["Error\n at RecordInvoker.commitLine (suitescript/resources/javascript/record/serverRecordService.js:278:5)\n at NetSuiteObject.thenableFunction() (suitescript/resources/javascript/record/proxy.js:115:24)\n at Object.onRequest (/SuiteScripts/Sales Orders/Suitelets/prepopulateLineItem.js:193:18)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"USER_ERROR","details":"Please choose an item to add","userEvent":null,"stackTrace":["Error\n at RecordInvoker.commitLine (suitescript/resources/javascript/record/serverRecordService.js:278:5)\n at NetSuiteObject.thenableFunction() (suitescript/resources/javascript/record/proxy.js:115:24)\n at Object.onRequest (/SuiteScripts/Sales Orders/Suitelets/prepopulateLineItem.js:193:18)"],"notifyOff":false},"notifyOff":false,"userFacing":true}

This is my SuiteLet
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define(['N/record', 'N/log', 'N/redirect'], function (record, log, redirect) {
  function onRequest(scriptContext) {
    try {
      const request = scriptContext.request;

      const salesOrderID = request.parameters.id;

      const salesOrder = record.load({
        type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
        id: salesOrderID,
        isDynamic: true
      });

      const itemFields = salesOrder.getSublistFields({ sublistId: 'item' });

      const excludeFields = [
        'commitinventory',
        'createpo',
        'custcol_rbs_date_auto_close',
        'custcol_ship_date_act',
        'custcolcust_linenum',
        'id',
        'item',
        'line',
        'linenumber',
        'lineuniquekey',
        'olditemid',
        'sys_id',
        'sys_parentid',
        'unitconversionrate',
        'units',
        'unitslist'
      ];

      var firstItemKeyValue = {};
      itemFields.forEach((fieldId) => {
        if (excludeFields.indexOf(fieldId) !== -1) return;
        const value = salesOrder.getSublistValue({
          sublistId: 'item',
          fieldId: fieldId,
          line: 0
        });
        if (value === null || value === undefined || value === '') return;
        log.debug({ title: 'fieldId - ' + fieldId, details: value });
        firstItemKeyValue[fieldId] = value;
      });

      const textFields = [
        'class',
        'class_display',
        'createdpo',
        'custcol_4601_witaxamount',
        'custcol_4601_witaxbaseamount',
        'custcol_category_salesforce_name',
        'custcol_item_type',
        'custcol_material_quality',
        'description',
        'item_display',
        'itemtype',
        'location_display',
        'pocurrency',
        'units_display'
      ];

      const dateFields = [
        'createddate',
        'ddistrib',
        'prevdate',
        'recordcreateddate',
        'saleseffectivedate'
      ];

      const booleanFields = [
        'amounthasbeenset',
        'backordered',
        'billvariancestatusallbook',
        'custcol_2663_isperson',
        'custcol_2663_isperson',
        'custcol_4601_witaxapplies',
        'dropshiporderhasbeenshiprecv',
        'dropshipwarningdisplayed',
        'fulfillable',
        'generateaccruals',
        'groupclosed',
        'includegroupwrapper',
        'isclosed',
        'isdropshiporderline',
        'islinefulfilled',
        'islinefulfilled',
        'isnoninventory',
        'isopen',
        'isposting',
        'isspecialorderline',
        'istaxable',
        'itempacked',
        'itempicked',
        'linked',
        'linked',
        'linkeddropship',
        'linkedordbill',
        'linkedshiprcpt',
        'noprint',
        'pomarginal',
        'povendor_display',
        'printitems'
      ];

      const integerFields = [
        'amount',
        'createdpo',
        'custcol_freight_estimate_amount',
        'custcol_material_form',
        'custcol_material_non_material',
        'custcol_material_quality',
        'custcol_material_type',
        'custcol_statistical_value_base_curr',
        'initquantity',
        'location',
        'onorder',
        'origlocation',
        'origquantity',
        'origunits',
        'poid',
        'povendor',
        'quantity',
        'quantityavailable',
        'quantitybilled',
        'quantityfulfilled',
        'rate'
      ];

      const floatFields = ['porate'];

      const filteredItemFields = Object.keys(firstItemKeyValue);
      salesOrder.selectNewLine({ sublistId: 'item' });
      salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'description',
        value: 'PLEASE UPDATE DESCRIPTION'
      });
      filteredItemFields.forEach((fieldId) => {
        if (textFields.indexOf(fieldId) !== -1) {
          salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: fieldId,
            value: firstItemKeyValue[fieldId]
          });
        } else if (dateFields.indexOf(fieldId) !== -1) {
          salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: fieldId,
            value: new Date(firstItemKeyValue[fieldId])
          });
        } else if (booleanFields.indexOf(fieldId) !== -1) {
          salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: fieldId,
            value:
              String(firstItemKeyValue[fieldId]).toLowerCase() === 'true' ||
              String(firstItemKeyValue[fieldId]).toLowerCase() === 't'
          });
        } else if (integerFields.indexOf(fieldId) !== -1) {
          salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: fieldId,
            value: parseInt(firstItemKeyValue[fieldId])
          });
        } else if (floatFields.indexOf(fieldId) !== -1) {
          salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: fieldId,
            value: parseFloat(firstItemKeyValue[fieldId])
          });
        } else {
          log.debug({
            title: 'without a type fieldId - ' + fieldId,
            details: "'" + firstItemKeyValue[fieldId] + "'"
          });
          salesOrder.setCurrentSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: fieldId,
            value: "'" + firstItemKeyValue[fieldId] + "'"
          });
        }
      });
      log.debug({ title: 'salesOrder', details: salesOrder });
      salesOrder.commitLine({ sublistId: 'item' });
      salesOrder.save({
        enableSourcing: false,
        ignoreMandatoryFields: false
      });

      const lastItem = salesOrder.getSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'item',
        line: salesOrder.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'item' }) - 1
      });

      redirect.redirect({
        url: '/app/common/item/item.nl?id=' + lastItem.id + '&e=T'
      });
    } catch (error) {
      log.debug({ title: 'error', details: JSON.stringify(error) });
    }
  }

  return { onRequest };
});


copying a line in a transaction and copy/cloning an item are two entirely different operations.  The fields available on an item do not have a 1:1 correlation with the transaction line fields and you cannot do directly what you are trying to do.

Thank you, @bknights, for your comment. Your comment clarifies why it was not working as I intended. Now, I am copying the item (as a record), and I think I will be able to address what I am trying to do.

I could tackle what I wanted, but not as I intended initially. @bknights' comment clarified my understanding of the issue and why I couldn't achieve what I wanted. The item record differs from the item list record on a Sales Order.
My solution was to get the first element from the items in the Sales Order list, load the item record, copy it, and save it.
const salesOrder = record.load({
  type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
  id: salesOrderID,
  isDynamic: true
});

...

const firstLineItem = salesOrder.getSublistValue({
  sublistId: 'item',
  fieldId: 'item',
  line: 0
});

...

const copyItem = record.copy({
  type: record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM,
  id: parseInt(firstLineItem)
});

...

copyItem.setValue({ fieldId: 'itemid', value: random.generateUUID() });
copyItem.setValue({ fieldId: 'displayname', value: 'Please update the description value' });
copyItem.save();

where record and random are from the NetSuite SuiteScripts 2.x Modules
